# Module in kt turn on java, error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] java.lang.String.split(

Tags: java, android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to run the following module:
https://github.com/petersamokhin/floating-hearts-view

The module is written in Kt, I have to run it on java.

So I did like this:

```
    HeartsView heartView = new HeartsView(this);
    heartView.applyConfig(new HeartsRenderer.Config(5f, 0.15f, 2f));
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.heart);

    //Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.heart);
    //Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();
    heartView.emitHeart(new HeartsView.Model(0, bitmap));
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.exoplayer/com.exoplayer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] java.lang.String.split(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2720)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1466)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6111)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] java.lang.String.split(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at org.rajawali3d.util.Capabilities.initialize(Capabilities.java:162)
        at org.rajawali3d.util.Capabilities.<init>(Capabilities.java:67)
        at org.rajawali3d.util.Capabilities.getInstance(Capabilities.java:73)
        at org.rajawali3d.materials.Material.<init>(Material.java:287)
        at org.rajawali3d.materials.Material.<init>(Material.java:274)
        at com.petersamokhin.android.floatinghearts.HeartsRenderer.initMaterial(HeartsRenderer.kt:104)
        at com.petersamokhin.android.floatinghearts.HeartsRenderer.emitHeart(HeartsRenderer.kt:37)
        at com.petersamokhin.android.floatinghearts.HeartsView.emitHeart(HeartsView.kt:50)
        at com.petersamokhin.android.floatinghearts.HeartsView.emitHeart$default(HeartsView.kt:46)
        at com.petersamokhin.android.floatinghearts.HeartsView.emitHeart(HeartsView.kt)
        at com.exoplayer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6734)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2720) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1466) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6111) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: add MainActivity.java code

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท it does actually. The library OP is using is using another library that attempts to check OpenGL extensions and split the returned String. The String is null, so it crashed.

Comment: The code is just the one I wrote.
So how can I solve, where is the real problem?

Comment: @TheWanderer: but what would be the null string? I do not pass any string.

Comment: @Paul no, that's not what I said. The base library attempts to read the available OpenGL extensions and then split the String of extensions. But that String is null. Try this on another device.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท decodeResource takes a resource, not a Drawable.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท: I tried both:
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource (this.getResources(), R.drawable.heart);

What so:
Drawable myDrawable = getResources(). GetDrawable(R.drawable.heart);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)myDrawable).getBitmap();

Nothing changes.

Comment: @TheWanderer: I tried on another device, same error.

Comment: Replace your implementation of the hearts library with this: `implementation 'com.github.zacharee:floating-hearts-view:19d5c8178e`. Does it still crash? (You may have to do a Gradle sync twice, as the first one may fail.)

Comment: @TheWanderer: Error: https://pastebin.com/M6qNx4Dd

Comment: @Paul see my answer, roll back to `com.github.petersamokhin:floating-hearts-view:0.0.3` and try to wait before emitting heart.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin: What should I use to wait?
Can you write an example?

Comment: @PeterSamokhin: Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Actions to do after 10 seconds
                heartView.emitHeart(new HeartsView.Model(0, bitmap));
            }
        }, 5000);

same error:     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] java.lang.String.split(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: @PeterSamokhin: I would ask you to try it yourself, write the java code I wrote above and let me know if it works.
I tried on different devices, different type of code, but nothing.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin: Version android 7.0.

Comment: @Paul see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wait (only first time!) **~300-500 ms** after activity start (i.e. before the first call) and then call `emitHeart`.

I think you can see something like `E/libEGL(8930): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)` in your `logcat` above/below your exception stacktrace.

I don't know the true reason and it might be the device or Android version specific issue.

---

Working code:

```
public class IssueTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_issue_test);

        LinearLayout rootView = findViewById(R.id.rootView);

        final HeartsView heartView = new HeartsView(this);
        heartView.applyConfig(new HeartsRenderer.Config(5f, 2f, 2f));

        rootView.addView(heartView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_heart_white);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        heartView.emitHeart(new HeartsView.Model(0, bitmap), HeartsView.MAX_Y_FULL);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();

    }
}
```

**res/layout/activity_issue_test.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#333333"
    tools:context=".fh.IssueTestActivity" />
```

And `ic_heart_white.png` is an image in `res/drawable` directory.

Tested on Google Nexus 5X emulator, API 28.